# GCD Implementation not working with PARSE Query (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, grand-central-dispatch

I've looked all over Stack Overflow and other web resources on how to handle the async PARSE query and storing this data into an array. I then use this array to populate a table in another view controller. Code structure is as follows:

AppController.swift:

```
public var BuisnessNames = [NSString]()
[...]
public func updateFeedsMap(){

    var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    var objects : [AnyObject]?
    var counter = 0

    query.whereKey("isProprietor", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.BuisnessNames.append(object ["BusinessName"] as! NSString)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RootVC.swift (inherits from AppController):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if isUserLoggedIn() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.updateFeedsMap()
        }
    }
```

RootVC segues to a third view controller in ViewDidAppear() which uses BuisnessNames array to populate a tableview. However, I am current not getting any data through to the table. I've spent many hours on this and I am out of ideas, please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is you request data in `viewDidLoad`,the process is async. It will return first.

Then you fire a segue in `ViewDidAppear()`,but at this time,you have not receive any data from the server.So,you tableview is always empty.

**Solution:**

Make a callback when data is received. Then do whatever you want with the data

A simple callBack demo

```
public func updateFeedsMap(completion:()->()){

    var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    var objects : [AnyObject]?
    var counter = 0

    query.whereKey("isProprietor", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.BuisnessNames.append(object ["BusinessName"] as! NSString)
                        }
                    }
                    //Here your data prase is done
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    completion()
                })
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then,your call the function like this

```
 self.updateFeedsMap { () -> () in
        //Here do something with data,reloadTableview or whatever you like
    }
```

Comment: I've tried various kinds of GDC controls and wrapping different sections of the codes in async/sync dispatches. I have even tried grouping dispatches and using completion callbacks...haven't been able to fix this yet. Could you suggest how you would do this?

Comment: Leo, nice explanation. However, would it make more sense to do `dispatch_apply` to iterate and run on a different thread so there can be concurrency? Or is `BusinessNames` thread-safe on the main thread only?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the GCD code you've added.  The `findObjectsInBackground` does the GCD work for you, and invokes the completion block on the main, which is where you want it to be.

You can remove the dispatches (both in `viewDidLoad` and in the find completion block).  Just fill your table's datasource array and tell the table to `reloadData`.  Remember the following other table view gotchas, like forgetting to connect datasource and delegate, or forgetting to initialize the array before filling it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply danh, I did as you suggested (removed GDC) and added a reloadData in the viewDidLoad of the 3rd VC. Still nothing! I am sure the table view gotchas are taken care of since I can add initial 'test' values to the array and they populate to the table view just fine.

Comment: Ok.  Lets start logging stuff.  In the completion block, log objects to see what the query got.  Log your table view, and your table view datasource which should == self.  Log the businessNames array.

Comment: Hi danh, I redid the code and added a button to force tableView reload after the Parse query has completed. This debug test worked! I think I just now need to employ the right type of GDC to wait for the businessNames array to populate before loading the table.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  But no need for any gcd code.  Just do the query, and in the completion block, initialize your array and reload data.